# does vmware change my ip machine? can change my ip machine?

Tags: ip, vmware, adsense

i want to know if I can change my machine ip, and what is the difference with network IP and machine ip..i don't know if the virtual machine has another IP different than the same pc...

this is for windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about VMware Workstation and/or Fusion, the answer to that will greatly depend on what your network setting is: Bridged, NAT, Host-Only

Bridged networking, default, gives your VM direct access to the network. Meaning that your PC and your VM will have their own IP addresses.

NAT networking is where your PC's IP will be shared with the VM.

Host-Only is where a network is created between only the PC and the VM. In this case, the PC and the VM will also have their own IPs but generally will not be on the same subnet as the network-reachable adapter of the PC.

More information: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D9B0A52D-38A2-45D7-A9EB-987ACE77F93C.html